# Protractor Test: Error: Angular could not be found on the page

Tags: angularjs, protractor

While running multiple test suits on CBT via jenkins parallel, Jenkins get slower and page takes more time to load on CBT and hence it shows below error(which is intermittent)
Error: Angular could not be found on the page Https:xxx.xyz.com If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.

Comment: Are you already using [browser.waitForAngular()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular)?

Comment: Is the page opened by `browser.get(<app url>)` an angular page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is not angular application, you need to turn of wait for angular. Usually login pages are not angular:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

To check if is angular, open dev tools and in console just write "angular", if page is angular will return object, if not will return "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined".